# How to see historical results for a TFS Work Item query?

Tags: tfs

I have a custom TFS Work Item query that looks something like this:

```
Work Item Type = Bug
AND Title CONTAINS "Login"
AND State <> "Closed"
```

intended to show me all current Login related bugs.  When I run it, I get results that look like this:

[image: Sample Login current bugs]

But what if I want to know what the results were when I ran this query a week ago?  Were there 20 open bugs back then?  The [ASOF capability in code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130326%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) appears to make this concept possible, but is there a way to do it through the TFS-provided Web interface or through Visual Studio Team Explorer?

Comment: I'm not aware of any support for `AsOf` in web or IDE queries (yet). AFAIK you can only use these from the TFS API. On the plus side the API is extremely easy to use, so that isn't as bad as it might sound - it wouldn't take much work to extract all the data you need for the given date/time and spit out something like CSV data that you can then easily view in Excel, for example.

Comment: You can vote for this feature on User Voice, spread it too! https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2155473-use-the-asof-operator-direct-in-the-user-interface

Comment: Brandao - Microsoft's acknowledgment on the page your link takes you to proves that what I seek to do in my question isn't currently possible.  If you post an answer including that link, I'll accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin on the visual studio gallery that provides what you are looking for:

- http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/852736b7-3a40-424f-bcfd-7a19f3f60837

I have not used it but it look like it will suit.

Comment: And I am fairly sure this feature no longer works in the Product